# langprop petition to reference StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, languages, trends

[langprop](http://langpop.com/) is a useful tool for gauging trends in programming languages. It references many sites to determine its ratings. It is my contention that langprop should use Stack Overflow. In my opinion, there is no better resource for determining what people are working on right now. Thoughts?

The Google group can be found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/langpop).

Comment: Is it langprop or langpop? You have it one way in the title and body and the other way in the tags.

Answer (score 3):

The results you would get from using StackOverflow would be heavily skewed towards C# and .NET in general. This is due to the overwhelmingly large audience of .NET people that first populated this site due to following the blogs of Jeff & Joel.

I would not necessarily base my assumptions of what is the most popular languages and technologies on the net based on what gets put on SO.

Comment: +1 don't really know why I feel this, but I agree.

Answer (score 0):

It, like just about every attempt to determine what people are using, will incorrectly rank Perl. The reason is that Perl people tend to hang out on irc. Most of the well known Perl programmers do not participate on Stack Overflow, that I can tell.

Some don't because of the Fastest-Gun, people who only have a passing knowledge of Perl answering questions about Perl.